# How to implement ConstraintLayout in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

ConstraintLayout is behaving inconsistently if a TextView has very fewer texts than other TextView wrapped in horizontal LinearLayout. If a character in left `TextView` is not much less than right `TextView` then it is working great.
Please refer red color texts and green color texts in attached screenshots.
[image: Buggy Screen][image: Desired screen]

Below is the XML for layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_F1F1F1"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/employee_name"
            android:textColor="@color/color_999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_date_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/date"
            android:textColor="@color/color_999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_name_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_date_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_role_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/employee_role"
            android:textColor="@color/color_999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_band_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/employee_band"
            android:textColor="@color/color_999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_date" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_role"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_role_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_band"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_band_header" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@color/color_E1E4EA"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_role" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_address"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_divider">
         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_green" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_origin_address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
         </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_red" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_destination_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_justification_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/justification"
            android:textColor="@color/color_999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ll_address" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_justification"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_justification_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_vehicle_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/vehicle_type"
            android:textColor="@color/color_999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_justification" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_vehicle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_vehicle_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Duration_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/distance"
            android:textColor="@color/color_999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_justification" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_Duration_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_start_time_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/start_time"
            android:textColor="@color/color_999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_vehicle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_end_time_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/end_time"
            android:textColor="@color/color_999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_duration" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_start_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_start_time_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_end_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_end_time_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_distance_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/trip_distance"
            android:textColor="@color/color_999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_start_time" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_edited_distance_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/edited_distance"
            android:textColor="@color/color_999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_end_time" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_distance_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_edited_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/color_D15900"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_edited_distance_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_edit_reason"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_distance" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_reject_reason"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_edit_reason">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/manager_reject_reason"
                android:textColor="@color/color_999999"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_rejection_reason"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_back"
            style="@style/FlatButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:text="@string/back"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ll_reject_reason" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Please ignore my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some bugs regarding wrap_content in constraintLayout version 1.0.2 as per google developer whom I talked. He suggested to use 1.1.0-beta4 version and by using version 1.1.0-beta4 my issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                            android:background="#F1F1F1">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_margin = "10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="employee_name"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_name"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_date_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="date_header"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv_name_header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_date"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_name_header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_role_header"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_date_header"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_date_header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_band_header"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_role_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="employee_role"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_band_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:text="employee_band"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_date"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_date"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_role"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="role"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_role_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_role_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_band"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="band"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_band_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_band_header" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_divider"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#E1E4EA"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_role"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_address"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_divider">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_origin_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:text="origin_address \n origin_address"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_destination_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address "
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_justification_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="justification_header"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_address" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_justification"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="justification"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_justification_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_justification_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_vehicle_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="vehicle_type"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_justification" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_vehicle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="vehicle"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_vehicle_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Duration_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="distance"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_justification" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="duration"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_Duration_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_start_time_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="start_time"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_vehicle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_end_time_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="end_time"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_duration" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_start_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="start_time"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_start_time_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_end_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="end_time"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_end_time_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_distance_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="trip_distance"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_start_time"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_edited_distance_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="edited_distance"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_end_time" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="distance"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_distance_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_edited_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="edited_distance"
            android:textColor="#D15900"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_edited_distance_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_edit_reason"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="edit_reason"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_distance" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_reject_reason"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_edit_reason">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="manager_reject_reason"
                android:textColor="#999999"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_rejection_reason"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="rejection_reason"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_reject_reason"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: your solution didn't solve the problem, if I use above xml then first 3-4 views are being cropped from top. Btw thanks for your time.

Comment: i had tried to resolve issue, after removing drawables path from xml , if you update your question, with resource files code like drawable, string and color. i will try it again..

Comment: you can remove drawables, and you have already replaced strings & colors. Basically, my code is working fine but it behaves weirdly when left textview has very fewer characters compare to right textview as marked in attached images, in that case back button on bottom not showing and if I use vertical_bias in button then in some cases it overlaps its above view.. you can check it with diff-2 character in both textview.. and again thanks alot for your valuable time.. :)

Comment: not solved :( , I have been also reported issue for 3 days to google but I haven't gotten any response. Reported issue on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71737537

Comment: I got response from google developer that they coudn't reproduce the issue and they suggested to use version 1.1.0 beta4 since they have fixed many issues regarding wrap_content. I will let you know if I'll get any solution. Btw thanks for your valuable time..:) happy learning :)

Comment: Hi Jaspreet, Issue has been fixed by using 1.1.0-beta4 version without changing my xml code. Many thanks!

Comment: Great... Good job, you can add the answer, so that it may help someone another who face the same kind of issue.

Comment: :) btw thanks for all your valuable time.. keep doing good works.. happy learning..:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add constraint bottom to your button,something like this

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"

        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:text="back"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ll_reject_reason"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Comment: in that case button is overlapping...issue not fixed.. btw thanks mate for your time..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                            android:background="#F1F1F1"
                                             >

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/NestedScrollView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bt_back"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_margin = "10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="employee_name"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_name"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_date_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="date_header"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv_name_header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_date"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_name_header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_role_header"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="date"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_date_header"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_date_header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_band_header"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_role_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="employee_role"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_band_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:text="employee_band"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_date"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_date"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_role"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="role"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_role_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_role_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_band"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="band"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_band_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_band_header" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_divider"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#E1E4EA"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_role"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_address"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_divider">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_origin_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:text="origin_address \n origin_address"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_destination_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address \n destination_address "
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_justification_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="justification_header"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_address" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_justification"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="justification"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_justification_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_justification_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_vehicle_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="vehicle_type"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_justification" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_vehicle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="vehicle"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_vehicle_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Duration_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="distance"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_justification" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="duration"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_Duration_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_start_time_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="start_time"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_vehicle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_end_time_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="end_time"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_duration" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_start_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="start_time"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_start_time_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_end_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="end_time"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_end_time_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_distance_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="trip_distance"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_start_time"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_edited_distance_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="edited_distance"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_end_time" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="distance"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_distance_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_edited_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="edited_distance"
            android:textColor="#D15900"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_edited_distance_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_edit_reason"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="edit_reason"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_distance" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_reject_reason"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_edit_reason"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="manager_reject_reason"
                android:textColor="#999999"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_rejection_reason"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="rejection_reason"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/NestedScrollView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I have made changes in layout, I think your issue get resolved now.

Comment: thanks Jaspreet for your time and efforts but I don't need to put back button outside scrollview, since requirement is to scroll back button along with other views..

Comment: you can check my another post, in that button is inside constraint layout. and not hidden when the destination address is larger that origin address