# ConstraintLayout within the NesteadScrollView Clipping bottom elements

Tags: android

Scrolling is stopped before reaches to the end and eventually clipping last one or two elements. Can anyone help me to resolve it.

## XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"
                android:contentDescription="V Gears"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/header_photo"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:title="V Gears"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/slogan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                android:padding="@dimen/app_spacing"
                android:text="@string/slogan"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextInverted"
                android:textSize="@dimen/section_heading_size"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/who_we_are"
                style="@style/heading"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/wwr_title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/slogan"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/who_we_are_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/app_spacing"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/app_spacing"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                android:text="@string/wwr_text"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/who_we_are"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/who_we_are"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/who_we_are"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/popular_gears"
                style="@style/heading"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/popular_gear_title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/who_we_are_text"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/who_we_are_text"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/who_we_are_text"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/popular_gears_layout"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/app_spacing"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/app_spacing"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/popular_gears"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_spacing">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="180dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/backpack"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_spacing"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_spacing_half">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/figureofeight"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/banner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/app_spacing"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/app_spacing"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:src="@drawable/banner"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/popular_gears_layout"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/other_gears"
                style="@style/heading"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/other_gears_title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/banner"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/other_gears_cards"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/app_spacing"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/app_spacing"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/other_gears"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_spacing"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_spacing_half">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="76dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/rope"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_spacing"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_spacing_half">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="76dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/snowboot"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_spacing"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_spacing_half">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="76dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/seatharness"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_spacing">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="76dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/sunglass"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/view_more_gears"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="view more gears"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bordered"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_spacing"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_spacing"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_spacing"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/other_gears_cards"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/get_in_touch_title"
                style="@style/heading"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/get_in_touch_title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_more_gears"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/full_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/get_in_touch_title"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="32dp"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_phone"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### Gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Comment: add `android:fillViewport="true"` property to `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: @JeelVankhede I have tried but not resolving..

Comment: Okay.. one more thing i found out, use height of contraint layout as `wrap_content` with fillviewport to nested scrollview

Comment: @JeelVankhede Thanks but it is still not resolving..

Comment: okay.. will look in to code and get back to you if found anything.

Comment: Have you tried this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48168289/how-to-implement-constraintlayout-in-nestedscrollview]

Comment: @vijikrish Thanks, I have just tried that solution by replacing my `1.0.2` support lib with `androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.1.0-beta4'` but it is giving me syn failed error. Or maybe I didn't understand exactly which part should I update. any idea, please?

Comment: @Code Lover, Could you please post your error message

Comment: @vijikrish I found that update was released around `Dec 17` and I have checked my lib is `1.1.3` so that answer doesn't resolve my issue. See the question, I have added gradle too

Comment: anyone please???